# Android: Efficiently draw on images

Tags: android, listview, canvas, bitmap, thumbnails

The helper function below draws a rectangle on top of input bitmap and returns a thumbnail bitmap. However, I run into java OutOfMemory Error when I call this helper around 1000 times from an activity to populate a list of thumbnails. I tried resizing the tempScaledBitmap to 375, 500 but the quality of the thumbnail image is poor.

Also, I was unable to directly draw on inputBitmap as it was immutable. 
What is an efficient way to display a list of 1000 plus thumbnails in an activity?

```
private static Bitmap drawOnCanvas(Bitmap inputBitmap, FramePoint[] points, ColorCode colorCode){
    Bitmap tempScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inputBitmap, 750, 1000, false);
    //draw path
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tempScaledBitmap);

    // Path
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(colorCode.equals(ColorCode.GREEN)?Color.GREEN:(colorCode.equals(ColorCode.RED)?Color.RED:Color.BLUE));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    Path p = new Path();
    p.moveTo(points[0].getPointX(), points[0].getPointY());
    p.lineTo(points[1].getPointX(), points[1].getPointY());
    p.lineTo(points[2].getPointX(), points[2].getPointY());
    p.lineTo(points[3].getPointX(), points[3].getPointY());
    p.close();
    canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
    return  tempScaledBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After each call to drawOnCanvas you should recycle your bitmaps:

```
 inputBitmap.recycle();
```

Also recycle the tempScaledBitmap after they are assigned to ImageViews or wherever to prevent this OOM errors.

Also, you could consider using [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). For me, it's the best option of all.

Comment: I see recycle is equivalent to freeing/deleting an image. But I'd require both the images, the input image and the tempScaledImage with rectangle drawn.

Comment: But you can not keep 1000 images on memory. You should free each thumbnail before loading the next one. Have you thought about using a lib like picasso or glide? It could be your best option and they are optimised.